# How to revoke the Distribution certificate in Apple developer portal?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I have one existing distribution certificate in apple developer portal. But, it is not working so I want to create another one in apple developer portal. But, there is an one option "Revoke" is available. If I select revoke the existing distribution certificate what will happen in XCode, KeyChain and the existing distribution certificate? and how can I create another new distribution certificate? Can you please clarify my doubt? The link is [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your effort. I have solved this problem. https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html this site helped me to solve my problem. It help any one in future.